# How to export information displayed in the template table to excel Django

Tags: django

I tried to export the information I display in the template under the table tag to excel, and the information was pulled from the SQL server. However, the exported csv only has headers in the file, I was wondering if anyone knows what might cause this?

**Here's my template:**

```
<body>

    <a href="{% url 'export_csv' %}">Export all PPs</a>
    <table class="myTable" id="myTable">

        <center>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Tracking Number</th>
                    <th>Delivery Date</th>
                    <th>Delivered</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {% for display in Project %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{display.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{display.TrackingNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{display.EstimatedDeliveryDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{display.Delivered}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </center>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Here's my model.py:**

```
    id = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    TrackingNumber = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    EstimatedDeliveryDate = models.DateField(max_length=25)
    Delivered = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

**Here's my views.py:**

```
    conn_Project = pyodbc.connect('driver={sql server};'
                                  'server=test;'
                                  'Database=test;'
                                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor_Project = conn_Project.cursor()

    selectedpp_p = request.POST.get('selectedpp_p', None)

    query_Project = """select id,TrackingNumber,EstimatedDeliveryDate,Delivered
    from Test.Project
    where Project = ?"""
    cursor_Project.execute(
        query_Project, selectedpp_p
    )
    result_Project = cursor_Project.fetchall()

    return render(request, 'introduction/project.html', {'Project': result_Project, 'selected_project': selected_project})

def export_csv_p(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Exported Table' + \
        str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.csv'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['ID', 'TrackingNumber', 'DeliveryDate', 'Delivered'])
    for project in Project.objects.all().values_list('ID', 'TrackingNumber', 'DeliveryDate', 'Delivered'):
        writer.writerow(project)

    return response
```

**Here's my url.py:**

```
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', introduction.views.project, name='project'),
    url(r'^export/csv/project/$', introduction.views.export_csv_p,
        name='export_csv_p'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Data Tables makes this fairly straightforward, if you’re okay with using a JavaScript library. Here’s a package we put together to automate this:

https://github.com/wharton/django-data-tables-tags

This does the export without a second query to the database as well!